# Does Webix treetable widget support dynamically add/delete/udpate tree node and corresponding table rows?

Tags: webix

I am not sure whether webix support this and I didn't find a workable code snippet to dynamically add/delete/udpate `tree node` and corresponding table rows in the treetable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know what you mean by "dynamic".
But yes, webix treetable allow "manual" add/delete/update of items :
See the documentation here : https://docs.webix.com/datatree__nodes_manipulations.html#addingnodes

Basic code to add item in treetable :

```
$$('treetable').add({value:'Hey !', state:'ok', hours:42}, 0, parentId);
```

See snippet for demo : https://snippet.webix.com/pcjwpwfs